# Display QString in MainWindow from DWORD thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4, network-programming

I'm writing an chat client and I want to display messages in MainWindow, like displayTextEdit->append(string); but I'm using the DWORD thread.

What is the way to do it? I have no idea, how to connect this thread with Mainwindow, any ideas?

```
DWORD WINAPI RECV_MESSAGE(int &s) //&s is a socket, from winsock2
{ 
    gg_header header; // incoming packet type
    gg_recv_msg in;   // text and user

    for(;;)
    {
        ::recv(s,(char*)&header,sizeof(header),0);
        if(header.type==RECV_MSG)
        {
            ::recv(s,(char*)&in,sizeof(in),0);

            QString string(in.message);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

thread is created in MainWindow:

```
CreateThread(NULL,1024,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &RECV_MESSAGE,&s,0,NULL));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare slot in your window that gets QString as param and processes it. Use QMetaObject::invokeMethod like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI RECV_MESSAGE(int &s) //&s is a socket, from winsock2
{ 
    QObject *ptrToWindowClass;
    gg_header header; // incoming packet type
    gg_recv_msg in;   // text and user

    for(;;)
    {
        ::recv(s,(char*)&header,sizeof(header),0);
        if(header.type==RECV_MSG)
        {
            ::recv(s,(char*)&in,sizeof(in),0);

            QString string(in.message);
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(ptrToWindowClass, "yourDefinedSlot", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, string));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Such call will process your slot in main thread, so everything will be done safely

Comment: I think I can't vote yet, to less reputation... But the solution doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Do you get any debug output? Check what does QMetaObject::invokeMethod return

Comment: Wow, it's working, my fault, thank you so much!
One more question: what is the best way to pass pointer and socket to this thread? CreateThread allows me to pass only one parameter, I tried do it by structure, but socket doesn't work with this.
Btw. Świat jest mały, nie spodziewałem się kogoś z Polski, pozdrawiam :)

Comment: If you're sure that there will be only one instance of that window you may use singleton pattern http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1921/Singleton-Pattern-its-implementation-with-C . As you will be using it between threads you must be sure that pointed object will not be destroyed before use of it. A ludzi z Polski jest tu wbrew pozorom nie tak mało ;) pozdrowienia

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a QObject derived class that your comm thread can use to communicate with your main window.

```
class CommSignaller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    SendMessage(const QString &msg);
public:
    Message(const QString &msg)
    {
        emit SendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Pass the main window pointer into the thread function and then connect the CommSignaller SendMessage signal to a slot in your main Window. Using the default connection type of QObject::connect, this communication is inherently thread-safe.